# How to change the origin of window form in c# ie top-left and openGL C ie center?

Tags: c#, c, opengl, visual-studio-2012

I am using C# to create GUI part to draw number of 2D rectangles one on the other and openGl C for generating 3D output of the same.I am using visual studio express edition 2012 for both.The problem i am facing is in c# the origin(0,0) is top-left and in openGl it is centered.So where ever i draw rectangles in 2D it will drawn from the center in openGL. i have tried getting X,Y values from 2D and able to pass it to 3D but output is not as required since openGl is center origin.

How can i resolve this problem?should i try changing origin of 2D c# or 3D openGL which one will be easier? i have already tried gluOrtho2D() dint worked out well for me.and Glulookat() to position the camera, but not sure how to exactly position the camera as per my requirement.Am i in the right path?Shoul i try changing c# origin?

My glorthocode,which i tried to position only the top-left part is ie (-x,y)

```
 gluOrtho2D(-0.1,0,0,0.1);
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem i am facing is in c# the origin(0,0) is top-left and in openGl it is centered.

Actually in OpenGL you have two origins:

- The viewport physical device units origin is in the lower-left of the viewport
- The Normalized Device Coordinates with the visible XY range being [-1…1]×[-1…1], i.e. the origin at the center, and -1,-1 being at the lower-left

The projection matrix is used to transform from view space to clip space, which after the so called "perspective divide" (p_NDC = p_clip / p_clip.w) becomes NDC space. If p_clip.w = w then clip coordinates are the NDC coordinates.

That being said, what you want is to create a mapping that places a given coordinate range in the viewport, with certain coordinates at certain corners/edges. `glOrtho(left, right, top, bottom, near, far)` does that. gluOrtho2D is probably the least useful function there is, because `gluOrtho2D(l,r,b,t) = glOrtho(l,r,b,t,-1,1)`.

Each of the parameters specifies which *view space* coordinate ends up at the given edge.

So lets assume the following:

```
glOrtho(
    -3 /* = left   */,
    -5 /* = right  */,
     4 /* = bottom */,
     3 /* = top    */,
    -1 /* = near   */,
     1 /* = far    */);
```

That means that the coordinate (-3, 4) ends up in the lower-left and (-5, 3) is upper-right. I think you can see where this is going. Say you want the origin be in the upper-left, hence top = 0, bottom = 0; This leaves the bottom and right coordinate to be chosen so that is matches your needs. Lets assume you want your view space match the viewport pixel coordinates then bottom = viewport_height, right = viewport_width.

```
glOrtho(0, viewport_height, 0, viewport_width, -1, 1);
```

However since OpenGL matrix operations happen in-place and work on whatever already is on top of the matrix stack, if you just call glOrtho without preparing a clean state before you'll see weird things happen. So the typical preamble for drawing pixel placed 2D graphics with fixed function pipeline OpenGL is:

```
glViewport(0, 0, viewport_width, viewport_height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, viewport_height, 0, viewport_width, -1, 1);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

draw_2D_pixel_dimensioned_stuff();

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPopMatrix();

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPopMatrix();
```

Answer (score -1):

using a scaling matrix with -1 on the axe to invert will do the trick I think

```
glScale(1,-1,1);
gluOrtho2D(0,screen_width,0,screen_height);
```

also reverting ortho bottom and top gives good results without scaling:

```
gluOrtho(0,800,600,0,-1,1);
```

Comment: Should i be doing this in c# or openGl code?where should i write this?

Comment: in openGL code, when you are rendering you interface, before any model matrix operation, you apply this scaling to the current matrix with [glScale](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glScale.xml)

Comment: Excuse me, I've done the test, you have to scale before applying the gluOtrho(0,800,0,600)